# Get filtered count of elements in array from $lookup along with the whole document

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query, aggregation-framework

I have this query in MongoDB:

```
db.emailGroup.aggregate([
    {
        "$lookup": 
        {
            "from": "link",
            "localField": "_id",
            "foreignField": "emailGroupId",
            "as": "link"
        },
    },
    {
        "$unwind": "$link"
    },
    {
        "$match": {
             'link.originalLink': ""
        }
    },
    {
        "$group" : {
            _id: '$_id',
            link: {
                $push: '$link'
            }
        }
    },
    {
        "$project": { 
            "size": { 
                "$sum": { 
                    "$map": { 
                        "input": "$link", 
                        "as": "l", 
                        "in": { 
                            "$size": {
                                "$ifNull": [
                                    "$$l.linkHistory", []
                                ]
                            }
                        } 
                    } 
                } 
            }
        }
    }
])
```

EmailGroup has partId field. I use $lookup to "join" other collection for sum her fields. I need group by partId field and sum custom field "size" for partId groups. Is this possible? Extra question: How can I add emailGroup fields to query result?

Sample documents:

emailGroup:

```
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("594a6c47f51e075db713ccb6"),
    "partId" : "f56c7c71eb14a20e6129a667872f9c4f",
}
```

link:

```
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("594b96d6f51e075db67c44c9"),
    "originalLink" : "",
    "emailGroupId" : ObjectId("594a6c47f51e075db713ccb6"),
    "linkHistory" : [ 
        {
            "_id" : ObjectId("594b96f5f51e075db713ccdf"),
        }, 
        {
            "_id" : ObjectId("594b971bf51e075db67c44ca"),
        }
    ]
}
```

Comment: You just need add `$group`on `partId` at the end with `$sum` to compute the `size` from `$project` stage. You will need to update your current `$group` & `$project` to include `partId` with `$first` operator ( and other fields you wish to keep in the outpur) so you can use in the final group.

Comment: On a side note, you can refactor your code to remove the  `$unwind` +`$match` + `$group` stage and replace that with `$filter ` inside of `$map` and change the `$project` stage to `$addFields`, which keeps the existing fields without including them explicitly.

Comment: @Veeram `$unwind + $match` is "not equal to" `$filter` and is in fact treated entirely differently by the server. The big difference being that the "server" actually "rolls up" the `$unwind` and `$match` into the `$lookup` itself. This is how MongoDB deals with results that can possibly exceed the BSON limit. By contrast adding `$filter` is only applied "after" the entire array is produced. Therefore `$unwind + $match + $group` is actually the better way to do this. Unfortunately there is no way to presently write the `$lookup` simply using the same syntax the server applies at this time.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

## Annotation for those looking for - Foreign Count

A bit better than was originally answered is to actually use the newer form of [`$lookup`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/lookup) from MongoDB 3.6. This can actually do the "counting" within the "sub-pipeline" expression as opposed to returning an "array" for subsequent filtering and counting or even using [`$unwind`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/lookup)

```
db.emailGroup.aggregate([
  { "$lookup": {
    "from": "link",
    "let": { "id": "$_id" },
    "pipeline": [
      { "$match": {
        "originalLink": "",
        "$expr": { "$eq": [ "$$id", "$_id" ] }
      }},
      { "$count": "count" }
    ],
    "as": "linkCount"    
  }},
  { "$addFields": {
    "linkCount": { "$sum": "$linkCount.count" }
  }}
])
```

Not what the original question was asking for but part of the below answer in the now most optimal form, as of course the result of [`$lookup`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/lookup/) is reduced to the "matched count" **only** instead of "all matched documents".

---

## Original

The correct way to do this would be to add the `"linkCount"` to the [`$group`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/group/) stage as well as a [`$first`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/first/) on any additional fields of the parent document in order to get the "singular" form as was the state "before" the [`$unwind`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/unwind/) was processed on the array that was the result of [`$lookup`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/lookup/):

**All Detail**

```
db.emailGroup.aggregate([
  { "$lookup": {
    "from": "link",
    "localField": "_id",
    "foreignField": "emailGroupId",
    "as": "link"    
  }},
  { "$unwind": "$link" },
  { "$match": { "link.originalLink": "" } },
  { "$group": {
    "_id": "$_id",
    "partId": { "$first": "$partId" },
    "link": { "$push": "$link" },
    "linkCount": {
      "$sum": {
        "$size": {
          "$ifNull": [ "$link.linkHistory", [] ]
        } 
      }   
    }
  }}
])
```

Produces:

```
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("594a6c47f51e075db713ccb6"),
    "partId" : "f56c7c71eb14a20e6129a667872f9c4f",
    "link" : [ 
        {
            "_id" : ObjectId("594b96d6f51e075db67c44c9"),
            "originalLink" : "",
            "emailGroupId" : ObjectId("594a6c47f51e075db713ccb6"),
            "linkHistory" : [ 
                {
                    "_id" : ObjectId("594b96f5f51e075db713ccdf")
                }, 
                {
                    "_id" : ObjectId("594b971bf51e075db67c44ca")
                }
            ]
        }
    ],
    "linkCount" : 2
}
```

**Group By partId**

```
db.emailGroup.aggregate([
  { "$lookup": {
    "from": "link",
    "localField": "_id",
    "foreignField": "emailGroupId",
    "as": "link"    
  }},
  { "$unwind": "$link" },
  { "$match": { "link.originalLink": "" } },
  { "$group": {
    "_id": "$partId",
    "linkCount": {
      "$sum": {
        "$size": {
          "$ifNull": [ "$link.linkHistory", [] ]
        } 
      }   
    }
  }}
])
```

Produces

```
{
    "_id" : "f56c7c71eb14a20e6129a667872f9c4f",
    "linkCount" : 2
}
```

The reason you do it this way with a [`$unwind`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/unwind/) and then a [`$match`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/match/) is because of how MongoDB actually handles the pipeline when issued in that order. This is what happens to the [`$lookup`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/lookup/) as is demonstrated the the `"explain"` output from the operation:

```
    {
        "$lookup" : {
            "from" : "link",
            "as" : "link",
            "localField" : "_id",
            "foreignField" : "emailGroupId",
            "unwinding" : {
                "preserveNullAndEmptyArrays" : false
            },
            "matching" : {
                "originalLink" : {
                    "$eq" : ""
                }
            }
        }
    }, 
    {
        "$group" : {
```

I'm leaving the part with [`$group`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/group/) in that output to demonstrate that the other two pipeline stages "disappear". This is because they have been "rolled-up" into the [`$lookup`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/lookup/) pipeline stage as shown. This is in fact how MongoDB deals with the possibility that the BSON Limit can be exceeded by the result of "joining" results of [`$lookup`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/lookup/) into an array of the parent document.

You can alternately write the operation like this:

**All Detail**

```
db.emailGroup.aggregate([
  { "$lookup": {
    "from": "link",
    "localField": "_id",
    "foreignField": "emailGroupId",
    "as": "link"    
  }},
  { "$addFields": {
    "link": {
      "$filter": {
        "input": "$link",
        "as": "l",
        "cond": { "$eq": [ "$$l.originalLink", "" ] }    
      }
    },
    "linkCount": {
      "$sum": {
        "$map": {
          "input": {
            "$filter": {
              "input": "$link",
              "as": "l",
              "cond": { "$eq": [ "$$l.originalLink", "" ] }
            }
          },
          "as": "l",
          "in": { "$size": { "$ifNull": [ "$$l.linkHistory", [] ] } }
        }     
      }
    }    
  }}
])
```

**Group by partId**

```
db.emailGroup.aggregate([
  { "$lookup": {
    "from": "link",
    "localField": "_id",
    "foreignField": "emailGroupId",
    "as": "link"    
  }},
  { "$addFields": {
    "link": {
      "$filter": {
        "input": "$link",
        "as": "l",
        "cond": { "$eq": [ "$$l.originalLink", "" ] }    
      }
    },
    "linkCount": {
      "$sum": {
        "$map": {
          "input": {
            "$filter": {
              "input": "$link",
              "as": "l",
              "cond": { "$eq": [ "$$l.originalLink", "" ] }
            }
          },
          "as": "l",
          "in": { "$size": { "$ifNull": [ "$$l.linkHistory", [] ] } }
        }     
      }
    }    
  }},
  { "$unwind": "$link" },
  { "$group": {
    "_id": "$partId",
    "linkCount": { "$sum": "$linkCount" } 
  }}
])
```

Which has the same output but "differs" from the first query in that the [`$filter`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/filter/) here is applied "after" **ALL** results of the [`$lookup`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/lookup/) are returned into the new array of the parent document.

So in performance terms, it is actually more effective to do it the first way as well as being portable to possible large result sets "before filtering" which would otherwise break the 16MB BSON Limit.

> Note: If you do not have [`$addFields`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/addFields/) available (added with MongoDB 3.4) then use [`$project`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/project/) and specify "ALL" of the fields you wish to return.

---

As a side-note for those who are interested, in future releases of MongoDB ( presumably 3.6 and up ) you can use [`$replaceRoot`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/replaceRoot/) instead of an [`$addFields`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/addFields/) with usage of the new `$mergeObjects` pipeline operator. The advantage of this is as a "block", we can declare the `"filtered"` content as a variable via [`$let`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/let/), which means you do not need to write the same [`$filter`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/filter/) "twice":

```
db.emailGroup.aggregate([
  { "$lookup": {
    "from": "link",
    "localField": "_id",
    "foreignField": "emailGroupId",
    "as": "link"    
  }},
  { "$replaceRoot": {
    "newRoot": {
      "$mergeObjects": [
        "$$ROOT",
        { "$let": {
          "vars": {
            "filtered": {
              "$filter": {
                "input": "$link",
                "as": "l",
                "cond": { "$eq": [ "$$l.originalLink", "" ] }    
              }
            }
          },
          "in": {
            "link": "$$filtered",
            "linkCount": {
              "$sum": {
                "$map": {
                  "input": "$$filtered.linkHistory",
                  "as": "lh",
                  "in": { "$size": { "$ifNull": [ "$$lh", [] ] } } 
                }   
              } 
            }  
          }
        }}
      ]
    }
  }}
])
```

Nonetheless the best way to do such "filtered" [`$lookup`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/lookup/) operations is "still" at this time using the [`$unwind`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/unwind/) then [`$match`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/unwind/) pattern, until such time as you can provide query arguments to [`$lookup`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/lookup/) directly.

> Note: By "directly" here I **do not mean** the "non-correlated" form of [`$lookup`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/lookup/) which should also be in the MongoDB 3.6 release, as this would indeed issue another "pipeline" execution for **each document** in the parent collection. So that feature still does not replace the present "best effective" way of retrieving only the matched items.

Comment: Thx for answer. A lot of new informations, but I didn't get about group by partId. When I use { "$group": { "_id": "$_id", "partId": { "$first": "$partId" }, "link": { "$push": "$link" }, "linkCount": { "$sum": { "$size": { "$ifNull": [ "$link.linkHistory", [] ] } } } }}  return many documents for choosen partId. I need one document with sum linkHistory for all documents with the same partId.

Comment: In sql I can realize subquery and group them. Is this possible in mongoDB? I'm new in MongoDB.

Comment: @niesuch What are you actually asking? You just want `partId` and the "sum" of the "linkCount" as generated from above? You mention "partId" in your question but it comes across as an "afterthought" more than what the actual question is about.

Comment: Ok, maybe I can't explain this. I give you example. A this moment I have that result:

Comment: @niesuch Look above. Added.

Comment: @niesuch You can "vote up" now as well [since your reputation now allows it.](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges)

Comment: I have one more question. How can I add new field using $addFields which meet condition for base collection (in my example emailGroup). I want add new field which sum "subject" (be in emailGroup) for given group.