# Mongo how to join two collection and add condition on second collection

Tags: mongodb, go, mongodb-query, mgo

I have two collections 
users{id, name} and files{id, userId, name} I want to find all the files whose file name "abc.xyz", I tried to write a code using $lookup but getting all the files belong to user and not filtering it by name  "abc.xyz", I have written following query.

```
db.user.aggregate([
{"$lookup": 
    {
        "from": "files", 
        "localField": "id", 
        "foreignField": "userId", 
        "as": "fileList"
    }
},
{"$project": { "filList":{
    "$filter": {
                    "input":"$fileList",
                    "as":"file"
                    "cond": {"$eq": ["$file.name","abc.xyz"]}
           }
             }
         }
}
])
```

Thank you

Comment: You are missing a `$`. So should be `$eq": ["$$file.name","abc.xyz"]` where it's `$$file` instead of `$file`. Also whilst this does work, it's actually not what you "should" be doing. The problem here is `$lookup` is returning "all" the documents matched by the foreign key, as opposed to also matching your given condition. In small result sets this is okay. But in real world cases you should do this differently.

Comment: Please let me know how to do it differently? I am new to mongoDB and your suggestions will be appreciated

Comment: Read [Get filtered count of elements in array from $lookup along with the whole document](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44888354/get-filtered-count-of-elements-in-array-from-lookup-along-with-the-whole-docume/44897438#44897438). Just answered and it explains the correct way to filter the array as a result of `$lookup`.

Answer (score 0):

> I want to find all the files whose file name "abc.xyz" … but getting all the files belong to user and not filtering it by name "abc.xyz"

Based on your question above, it could also be interpreted as "Find all files with name `abc.xyz` along with its owner information".

In which case, it would be better to filter the files collection first using [$match](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/match/) to filter file name equal to `abc.xyz`. This would limit the number of documents to look-up into `users` collection, instead of perfoming lookup for both collections then perform filtering.

For example:

```
db.files.aggregate([
    {"$match": {"name":"abc.xyz"}},
    {"$lookup": {
                "from": "users", 
                "localField": "userId", 
                "foreignField": "_id", 
                "as": "users"
                 }
     }]);
```

Please note that the collection is now reversed, from `files` looking up into `users`. An example result would be:

```
  "result": [
    {
      "_id": 111,
      "userId": 999,
      "name": "abc.xyz",
      "owner": [
        {
          "_id": 999,
          "name": "xmejx"
        }
      ]
    },
    {
      "_id": 222,
      "userId": 998,
      "name": "abc.xyz",
      "owner": [
        {
          "_id": 998,
          "name": "kalwb"
        }
      ]
    }
  ]
```

I would also recommend to check out:

- [Data Model Examples with Patterns](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/applications/data-models/)
- [Aggregation Pipeline Optimisation](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/core/aggregation-pipeline-optimization/)